# File creation of specific length in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a new file with a specific length. 
By using below code, the file gets created.
The problem is the length of the file created is 0kb's.
Also, the text under stream writer is not written in the file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Filesize
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"D:\\demotext2.txt");
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\\demotext2.txt", true);
            try
            {
                while (fi.Length >= (2 * 1024 * 1024))
                {

                        sw.WriteLine("Demo File");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger. It should be fairly obvious from there.

Comment: Should it be `fi.Length <= (2 * 1024 * 1024)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a Huge Dummy File in a Matter of Seconds in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881050/creating-a-huge-dummy-file-in-a-matter-of-seconds-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @CarbineCoder has probably answered your question. You should also be aware that just calling `ToString` on your exception won't give you any information. Do you want `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength.aspx

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(strCombined, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        fs.SetLength(oFileInfo.FileSize);
    }
```